# Axios Patch On FeathersJs No auth token

Tags: feathersjs

I have a problem with Patch in FeathersJS.

I want to update the data with axios.patch

but the message that appears is always No auth token

```
{"name":"NotAuthenticated","message":"No auth token","code":401,"className":"not-authenticated","data":{},"errors":{}}
```

This my axios :

```
Aktifasi() {
  axios.patch(process.env.ROOT_API+'/ek_user?id_user=2',
  qs.stringify({
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    active_user: 1
  }))
  .then(request => this.AktifasiSuccesSend(request))
  .catch((error) => this.AktifasiFailedSend(error))
},
AktifasiSuccesSend (request) {
  console.log('Yay');
},
AktifasiFailedSend (error) {
  console.log('Oh Fail');
}
```

And this Hook on FeathersJS :

```
   before: {
    all: [],
    find: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    get: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    create: [ hashPassword() ],
    update: [ hashPassword(),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    patch: [ hashPassword(),  authenticate('jwt') ],    
    remove: [ authenticate('jwt') ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Axios configuration documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) shows, `headers` are passed as a separate option not as a stringified query string (which shouldn't be necessary at all):

```
const data = {
  active_user: 1
};
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
};

axios.patch(process.env.ROOT_API + '/ek_user?id_user=2', data, config);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend becoming very good at using a proper Node debugger.  Visual Studio Code has a great debugger.  I even wrote an article about it on the Feathers blog: https://blog.feathersjs.com/debugging-feathers-with-visual-studio-code-406e6adf2882

I will give you some pointers to get you on your way, but you will be required to answer your own question by using a debugger.

The "No auth token" message that you are getting is coming from the `authenticate('jwt')` hook.  Here are some typical steps you'd use to solve your own problem:

- If you open that hook in your node_modules folder and put break points in it before the message, you'll be able to see where it's looking for a jwt token.
- If you create a hook before all other hooks in the `patch` hooks, you'll be able to put a break point in it and inspect the hook context object to see if the request contains the jwt, or not (in the same location that the `authenticate` hook expects it.
- If the jwt token is not in the place where the `authenticate` hook expects to find it, you may be missing a middleware function registration in your `authentication.js` setup file.  You would check the feathers docs to make sure you've properly registered the authentication plugins.